# Working with several tables - SQL - Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

I have:

Table x:
Key|First name|Last name|Phone|E-Mail| etc..

Table y:
Key|Global number|Very important information, that can be only in y.

Global number from y associated with code from x, so I can find necessary information from x using Global number.
First time (when I used TADOTable) I could get the necessary field using `Locate()`. Now I am using TADOQuery and I need to make such SQL-query, that will return such table, that would contain Global number and the fields, that are associated with fields from x.
Can somebody give me this query?

P. S. I tried to make this query by my-self but it didn't worked, because I couldn't use WHERE so: `WHERE x.Key=[y.Global number]`. 
I just got a type mismatch.

What I have done!?

When I checked types, I found, that when I created the Database I didn't changed the default type (text) to integer, so when I used it from TADOTable, Delphi just automatically converted types.

Comment: Which server are you using?  Also could you add the Sql definitions of your two tables and the exact code which gives the type-mismatch error, please?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what SQL database you are using. If your database supports it you can use a join statement:

```
select Key, GlobalNumber, FirstName, LastName, Phone, etc
from   x
join   y on y.GlobalNumber = x.Key
where  whatever
```

What are the datatypes of Key and GlobalNumber?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need cast one of matching fields type to another CAST(x.Key as )